# How to count number of rows in each file of a corpus in R

Tags: r, row, corpus

Simple question... given for example:

```
data("crude")
```

which is a corpus with 20 text documents, how do I get something like:

```
1  4
2  6
3  5
4  3
etc...
```

where the second column is the number of rows of each document in the corpus "crude"? Or even a vector of row numbers would work.

NROW/nrow don't seem to work.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Are you sure you want to find out row in each document? Because this doc contains plain text... Check `crude[[1]]` ... Its no longer data.frame or vector format

Comment: Hrmm... so by the time it's put into a corpus it's too late?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can count line feed (LF) with

```
library(stringr)
str_count(string = crude[[1]], pattern = "\\n")
# [1] 11
```

`crude[[1]]` have 12 rows on my computer, so for all the corpus you can do this :

```
sapply(crude, FUN = function(x) str_count(string = x, pattern = "\\n") + 1)
```

Comment: Yup.. exakly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from line if your actual data was data.frame then you can find out number of items. Check this

```
data = data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5,z=1:5)
corp = Corpus(DataframeSource(data))
corp[[1]] 
#Output
 1
 1
 1

lapply(corp,length)
#Output
 $`1`
 [1] 3

 $`2`
 [1] 3

 $`3`
 [1] 3

 $`4`
 [1] 3

 $`5`
 [1] 3
```